# magento 2.2 composer checking pubkeys fail

Tags: magento2, composer

when i run a composer diagnose i get some errors, first of al i have to update my current composer version. But more of my concern is the FAIL on pubkeys.

Wich keys are this? The magento authentication keys or some others?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `composer self-update --update-keys` to update **[pubkeys](https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html)**.

> For example:

```
Enter Dev / Snapshot Public Key (including lines with -----):

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

```
Enter Tags Public Key (including lines with -----):
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

`composer diagnose;` to check if everything worked out.

> For example:

```
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4839

find key automatically
Open https://composer.github.io/pubkeys.html to find the latest keys.